# Proper HTML syntax for this 'icon' block

Tags: html, css, syntax, icons

Ok, so im trying to remake my website and i wanted to ask if this HTML syntax im using is proper.

The HTML code is something like this:

```
<a href="http://the_url.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="../img/id.png" width="32" height="32" alt="id" />
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="des">Description</p>
</a>
```

and for the CSS i mainly make the  tag to display as block.

Is this proper coding or should i remake it a different way? You can see an example at http://varemenos.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html) of the `<a>` tag, this syntax is valid. It was not in former HTML versions.

If the construct suits its semantic meaning is still up to you and the actual content. If you use it for short snippets of text (esp. in the description), I think it's fine. If the content gets longer, you might want to think about splitting it up and moving the anchor a bit down the hierarchy to make it clearer to the users which parts of the page are actually link targets.

Answer (score 1):

This website may interest you: [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvaremenos.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2).

According to the validator, your website is HTML5 valid.

Comment: Which downvote machine walked over this page? (I don't mind, I had already reached the daily rep cap for today).

Answer (score -1):

You are using block elements (`h4` and `p`) inside an inline element (`a`). This isn't "proper".

This can be fixed by adding a CSS rule so that the `a` has `display:block` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Adding CSS rules does not make invalid markup valid. Block elements are NEVER allowed inside of inline elements, regardless of any other stuff.

Comment: `display:block` or `display:inline-block` makes it a block element, so it's not an inline element anymore, so there's no problem.

Comment: It makes it behave like a block element but does not actually make it one according to the DTD (for HTML versions which where defined with a DTD or an XML schema). HTML5 actually changed that definition so that the `<a>` tag is [transparent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/terminology.html#transparent), meaning that if it is contained in an element allowing flow (aka. block) elements, it can contain flow elements itself. So if the `<a>` tag of the OP is contained in e.g. a div, it is correct syntax in HTML5 (but not former versions).